# Contents are getting overlap in landscape when using recycler view and card view

Tags: android

I am using recycler view and cardview for the first time. My problem is when it is in potrait, it looks good but when screen is rotated to landscape the card view content are not fully visible.

Thanks in advance.[Potrait image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLUvp.png)

[Landscape image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqIMF.png)

Comment: post your xml content

Comment: would it able to show your xml layout file and adapter ?